# Are there historical examples of non-Christian martyrs who were persecuted and killed because they claimed to be firsthand eyewitnesses of a miracle?

Tags: religion, religious-history, death, reference

In the context of Christianity, the obvious examples are the apostles, who claimed to have been firsthand eyewitnesses of the resurrection of Jesus (with the exception of the apostle Paul, who didn't witness the resurrection but still claimed to have had a "Damascus Road" encounter). They maintained their testimonies despite opposition, persecution and even death as martyrs.

Are there similar historical examples **outside** of Christianity?

To be clear, a Muslim Jihadist would not count as an example unless he explicitly claimed to have been a firsthand eyewitness of a miracle and maintained his testimony in spite of persecution until martyrdom.

The [Wikipedia article on martyrs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martyr) was obviously the first thing I checked before I posted this question, but I was not able to identify a specific case of non-Christian martyrdom in which the reason for the persecution was that the individual claimed to have been a firsthand witness of a miraculous event, leading to beliefs that endangered established orthodoxies, the established order or anything of that sort.

I also attempted to find examples by googling "martyr eyewitness miracle" and similar queries, but I only managed to find Christian examples, such as the [Martyrdom of Polycarp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martyrdom_of_Polycarp), which allegedly involved miraculous events (see the first paragraph in the Wikipedia article).

Comment: [Movie recommendation](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108185).

Comment: Does the 6th Dalai Lama count?

Comment: @MCW - It is not clear at all if those non-Christian martyrs referenced in the Wikipedia article were persecuted because they claimed to have witnessed a supernatural event/miracle.

Comment: @Jan - What was the 6th Dalai Lama firsthand witness of? Why was he persecuted?

Comment: @MCW - `I think even a casual reading of the Old Testament or the Koran would indicate that this question is too basic.` - Is there any specific historical figure mentioned in any of those books that you have in mind?

Comment: Inguess he was witness of having previous incarnations? And he was persecuted for being perceived as being a reincarnation?

Comment: Are there *Christian* examples of such a thing? In general the Christian "Apostles" were killed for preaching against the state religion, or for being prominent figures in a reviled religious minority. Nobody much cared if they thought they witnessed miracles or not.

Comment: @Jan - Oh, I see. And did he maintain his testimony until death, despite the persecution? If so, I think that would be a valid example.

Comment: The massacre at the Prat dels Cremats may be another example, although the claim that the Cathars were not Christians has come under some serious dispute in recent years.

Comment: @T.E.D. - [Jesus Christ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesus) and [Stephen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Stephen) were supposedly accused of blasphemy and killed because they made outrageous supernatural claims according to the Jews. And it is my understanding that the apostles made a big deal of their testimonies when they preached, as they started making disciples, so their testimonies played a very important role in my opinion, at least at the beginning of Christianity.

Comment: @Spirit Realm Investigator Since no-one really knows how and when exactly the sixth Dalai Lama died, his opinions from right before his death are also unknown.

Comment: Let's avoid talking about Jesus himself, because he specifically wasn't asked about, and what he was actually historically killed for is a whole other topic. Stephen however was 100% killed for [preaching against Judaism](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Saint-Stephen). That's what "speaking against the Holy Place and the Law" means.

Comment: And let's not get into a discussion of what is inside/outside Christianity.  Most of my acquaintances insist that Catholicism and Latter Day Saints are not Christian religions....

Comment: What about _[Wikipedia:pagan martyrs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Pagan_martyrs)_? Most of my pagan friends would also suggest that [Burning times](https://www.learnreligions.com/what-were-the-burning-times-2562890) would fulfill the requirements.  or [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Does-paganism-have-any-martyrdom-stories); arguably the [Benedanti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benandanti) qualify

Comment: Does [Joseph Smith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Smith#Death) count?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - Interesting case. It kind of does? But at the same time, there are [reasonable objections](https://seanmcdowell.org/blog/was-joseph-smith-a-martyr) to his martyrdom that make his case look less convincing than, say, the 1st century apostles.

Comment: @T.E.D.: Indeed, if the authorities (or members of mobs) thought that a would-be martyr had  actually witnessed real miracles, they might be rather cautious about doing anything to them, on the grounds that if their deity could do THAT, He/She/It could just as easily smite US.  So what they really thought they were doing was taking action against the spreaders of outrageous lies.  We only have to look at current US politics to see how much trouble can be caused by an outrageous lie that's believed by the gullible.

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens: Was Smith killed for supposed "miracles", or because his polygamist lifestyle offended against then-current ideas of morality?  We might make a present-day comparison to the death of Jeffrey Epstein.

Comment: @jamesqf: There seems to be some legal ambiguity about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is going to be very difficult to answer because the criteria are muddled and not subject to analysis by historical methods and techniques.  Until/unless the following are clarified, the question is going to be subjective.

Someone will argue each of the examples below, because there are:

1. no empirical evidence of miracles,
2. no clear criteria to classify miracles and; (I am not qualified to judge whether an Islamic Shahid did or did not witness something miraculous)
3. often no formal legal grounds on which an individual is martyred. (@T.E.D addresses this much more effectively in comments). Arguably the Yasukini martyrs were killed because of their belief in the supernatural status of their Emperor; I am not qualified to evaluate whether there are any miracles involved.
4. No clear definition of Christian. I've been told that Catholics aren't Christian, that Latter Day Saints aren't Christian, etc.  There is no empirical, objective test for Christianity.

The following are examples of people who died for their faith, where that faith involves belief in the supernatural

- *[Wikipedia:pagan martyrs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Pagan_martyrs)*?
- [Burning times](https://www.learnreligions.com/what-were-the-burning-times-2562890) would fulfill the requirements.  or [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Does-paganism-have-any-martyrdom-stories);
- [Benedanti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benandanti)
- [Aum Shinrikyo](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-35975069)
- [Heaven's Gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaven%27s_Gate_(religious_group))
- [Native Americans](https://www.nationalgeographic.org/article/native-americans-and-freedom-religion)

Comment: That last bullet reminds me about the events surrounding the Wounded Knee massacre of 1890. There was a belief in [spirit shirts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_shirt) that would repel bullets. This was certainly miracle-based thinking, and it certainly got rather a lot of people killed.

Comment: (You'll typically find these issues discussed as the "ghost dance" and "ghost shirts", but that's a 19th century translation of a Lakota concept, and IMHO inaccurately makes it sound more silly than necessary today. What they believed in was more like The Force than western ghosts).

Comment: @T.E.D.: The Ghost Dance movement wasn't Lakota.  It originated with the Northern Paiute leader Wovoka, though many of the western tribes adopted it.

Comment: @jamesqf - I suggest you read that link in my comment. The bullet-proof shirts were a Lakota "innovation", not part of Wovoka's theology. Also, Wounded Knee, the massacre that made the dance famous to non-indians, was in Lakota territory, and it was largely their people who died there.

Comment: @T.E.D.: To be honest, I'd never associated Wounded Knee with the Ghost Dance, and I know of Wovoka mainly because he's part of my local history.

Comment: @jamesqf - Well, I don't know if this is right (a lot about his life appears to be disputed, or at least very vague), but as near as I can tell from skimming various WP pages, "Wovoka" was actually what the Lakota called him, not his Paiute name. His birth name was "Quoitze Ow", and whites he dealt with before his prophet days called him "Jack Wilson".